# How to mock .each and .find method in jQuery using Jack?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking

I'm currently trying to mock the following method using Jack.  The code example is as below:

```
var ID = "id";
$('#' + ID + ' > div > table').each(function) {
    var nodeSpan = $(this).find('span.' + NODE_INDICATORS)[0];
.
.
.
});
```

How should I approach it?  Are there jQuery/QUnit functions that allows me to create a DOM node/element which I can use to mock the find method?  Or can this be done easily with Jack?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up supplying a DOM structure to pass the jquery code instead of mocking it.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is make nodes as part of your test, you can just use the HTML "signature" of the jQuery method; for instance:

```
$(someNode).append("<DIV id='55'>I'm a DIV!</DIV>");
```

If that's not what you're trying to do, maybe try to explain your question better?